# How to send e-mail with attachment from terminal?

Tags: email, sendmail, attachment

I'm new to Ubuntu. Can anybody help me about how to send emails from terminal?

Comment: `mail --attach=filename user@domain`. See `man mail` for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, I am a bit rusty on this, so forgive me if it is not exactly right :-)

If you have an ubuntu host with properly configured sendmail then you can encode the file as base64 uuencode and pipe it to sendmail:

```bash
cat myfile.txt | uuencode --base64 myfile.txt | mailx -s "subject" praveen@home
```

If you have another type of mail client then you have to explore what possibilitie you have to run that at the command line.  The important point is the `uuencode --base64 filename.ext`, which ensures the file is encapsulated properly so it is understood as an attachment by the recipient.

Answer (score 0):

Install mailutils utility on the server. Make sure the SMTP server (Such as Postfix) is working properly on the server.

```bash
apt install mailutils
```

After installation. You can use the `mailx` command.

```bash
mailx -A testfile.txt -s "testmail" recipient@domain.name < /dev/null
```

Output:

```
mailx: Null message body; hope that's ok
```